# How to test Github dependabot webhooks

Tags: github, dependabot, github-webhook

I am working on setting up a Github webhook that fires off when a dependabot alert is created. The goal is integrating with Jira automation, but that's not particularly relevant to this question.

I know there is documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#dependabot_alert); however, I'd like to test my integration rather than just waiting for dependabot alerts to come through. So, my question is: is there any way to manually trigger a dependabot alert?

Comment: Are you creating a GitHub app? Do you have an existing repository with dependencies you know haven't been updated in a while but doesn't have dependabot alerts turned on yet? That way, you can create your GitHub app that listens to `dependabot_alert.created` events, install it on that repository and then turn on alerts for the repo.

Comment: @OpeAdeyomoye thanks for the reply. Yes, I have all of those things configured. Alerts are being properly created as expected, and the webhook is firing. I was just wondering if there was a way to *Manually* trigger an alert, so I could fire off that webhook whenever I want for testing purposes.